# How the Zero-point Energy of the System containing 2 Fermions in 3 Micro-Energy States is 1?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, fermions, partition-function, data-analysis

If we distribute 2 Fermions $\mathrm{(A,A)}$ in 3 Micro-Energy States (0,$\epsilon$,$2\epsilon$), the confirmation is given by :
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 0 & \varepsilon & 2 \varepsilon & E_{i} & g_{i} \\
\hline A & A & & \varepsilon & 1 \\
\hline & A & A & 3 \varepsilon & 1 \\
\hline A & & A & 2 \varepsilon & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

And the corresponding Partition Function of the System is given by : $$Z=1×e^{-\frac{\epsilon}{k_BT}}+1×e^{-\frac{2\epsilon}{k_BT}}+1×e^{-\frac{3\epsilon}{k_BT}}$$

From this Partition Function of the System, we can calculate the Average Energy of the System which is given by $$U=-\frac{\partial lnZ}{\partial \beta}\Rightarrow U(T)=\frac{1×e^{-\frac{\epsilon}{k_BT}}+2×e^{-\frac{2\epsilon}{k_BT}}+3×e^{-\frac{3\epsilon}{k_BT}}}{1×e^{-\frac{\epsilon}{k_BT}}+1×e^{-\frac{2\epsilon}{k_BT}}+1×e^{-\frac{3\epsilon}{k_BT}}}$$

When I try to plot $T$ vs $U(T)$ we get [image: U(T) vs T]

As we can see from the plot, $U(T=0K)=1$. But if I try to get it analitically i.e.
$$
\lim _{T \rightarrow 0} U(T)=\lim _{T \rightarrow 0}\frac{1×e^{-\frac{\epsilon}{k_BT}}+2×e^{-\frac{2\epsilon}{k_BT}}+3×e^{-\frac{3\epsilon}{k_BT}}}{1×e^{-\frac{\epsilon}{k_BT}}+1×e^{-\frac{2\epsilon}{k_BT}}+1×e^{-\frac{3\epsilon}{k_BT}}}=\frac{0}{0} form
$$
– this can't even be solved by using L'Hôpital's Rule because the $\frac{0}{0}$ form comes again and again.

How can I prove $U(T=0K)=1$ ?

Comment: Multiply the numerator and the denominator by $e^{\epsilon/k_{\rm B}T}$.

Comment: @YvanVelenik thank you